# file_get_contents fails to open stream but curl gives 401 error

Tags: php, curl, svg, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use file_get_contents to grab and svg and put it on the page. On the clients server it gives the error "failed to open stream". Some of the suggestions I found to fix this was use curl but when I did so I got an error 401 unauthorized access.

Any ideas what I could do to get one of the two methods fixed?

```
function curl_get_contents($url){
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

echo curl_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/logo.svg');
```

Comment: It is possible that they are blocking scripted access. Look up examples of making curl pretend to be Internet Explorer. If that doesn't work, it may be that they require the referrer to be one of their pages (no leeching allowed). Again, you can use curl to fake the referrer as necessary.

Comment: Where is your code? Both errors can reefer to an invalid path being accessed.

Comment: is the resource you are trying to access public? might that be the reason?

Comment: The SVG is stored on the same server, if I go to the URL for the SVG in the browser I'm able to access it just fine. I'll add my curl code in a sec.

Comment: Try add: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The site is password protected and you need to pass additional parameters to file_get_contents for it to be accessible this way. Not something I've ever ran into before.

Comment: that seemed like a plausible cause